Insert association with @ManyToMany hibernate without knowing if associated data exist
I have two entities, Content and Data connected with a relation @ManyToMany.
Content is the owner of the relationship so my code looks like that:
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class ContentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CONTENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    // some stuff
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "content_data",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumns(name = "CONTENT_ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumns(name = "DATA_ID")
    private Set<DataEntity> dataEntities;

    // Getters & Setters
    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "data")
public class DataEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    // some stuff
    // Getters & Setters
    
}

I want to be able to insert into content table and in the same time insert links into the content_data association table, but without knowing if the data already exist in the database (I want to insert a content with some data objects in it, but some of them already exists and some don't).
I use the method save from my ContentRepository which extends JpaRepository.
I have tried changing the cascade type but I can't figure how it works...
I've tried to set it to {MERGE, PERSIST}, only to MERGE or only to PERSIST or no cascade at all but I get either an integrity error (UnexpectedRollBackException) as I'm trying to create an association with a Data that does not exist, or the error detached entity passed to persist.
I want to avoid if possible to check manually with my repository if each data exist or not.

Post the sql that hibernate is generating. Then we can monitor the behavior of hibernate. Before that Remove FetchType.EAGER and try again.


I want to be able to insert into content table and in the same time insert links into the content_data association table, but without knowing if the data already exist in the database (I want to insert a content with some data objects in it, but some of them already exists and some don't).

If you want to cascade save() across the association then you can save new / transient ContentEntity objects that have a combination of new and managed DataEntity objects associated with them, and even removed ones should be ok, but you cannot mix a new ContentEntity with detached DataEntitys. This is because because Spring will use a JPA persist() on the ContentEntity, and that will fail when it cascades to a detached entity.
That some of your attempts produce a message about attempting to persist detached entities suggests that such entities are at least part of the problem.  You haven't presented enough information to determine how you are ending up with detached entities, but it could be as simple as storing entity objects in a session that outlives the EntityManager from which they were obtained (via your repository).  In that case, it is possible that detachment could be avoided by using a persistence context with extended scope, supposing that you are not already doing so, but this has additional implications.
If you have to deal with detached entities then you have three main options for doing so:

just keep them away from your persistence context.  You can use them for other purposes, as POJOs.

replace them, at need or in bulk, by fetching new, managed ones.  You should exercise this option if you need managed entities and there is any chance that the detached ones contain stale state that should not override the DB.

merge() them, at need or in bulk.  This reattaches them to the persistence context, but also makes their current state persistent.  This will cause you trouble if these entities are stale with respect to the DB, unless overwriting the current persistent state with the stale state is what you actually want.


All of these options require you to know (as a consequence of program flow or internal metadata) which entity objects are detached, or else to check (via the relevant entity manager's contains() method, though this does not distinguish between new and detached entities).  For example, with a transaction-scoped entity manager, you should know where the top-level transaction boundaries are, and you know that entities become detached when they cross from within to without.
Side note:
You should give careful consideration to what operations you want to cascade from content to data entities.  You apparently do want to cascade PERSIST operations.  You almost certainly do not want to cascade REMOVE operations.  You probably do not want to cascade DETACH operations, and you might or might not want to cascade MERGE operations.
Also, some versions of Hibernate have additional, custom cascade types that you might need to enable explicitly to support your intended use if you do not use CascadeType.ALL.
